# installing gtk-sharp2 on Centos7

Tags: yum, gtk

I'm trying to instal (on centOS 7) this package but I got this error below ( I admit that I'm a novice with yum as well):

```
sudo yum install gtk-sharp2

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, protectbase

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
 * elrepo: ftp.nluug.nl
 * epel: mirror.netcologne.de
 * extras: centos.copahost.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.rackspeed.de

0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gtk-sharp2.x86_64 0:2.12.11-12.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gtk-sharp2 = 2.12.11-12.el7 for package: gtk-sharp2-devel-2.12.11-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mono(glib-sharp) = 2.12.0.0 for package: gtk-sharp2-2.12.26-0.x86_64
---> Package gtk-sharp2.x86_64 0:2.12.26-0 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glib-sharp2.x86_64 0:2.12.26-0 will be installed
---> Package gtk-sharp2.x86_64 0:2.12.11-12.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gtk-sharp2 = 2.12.11-12.el7 for package: gtk-sharp2-devel-2.12.11-12.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: gtk-sharp2-devel-2.12.11-12.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: gtk-sharp2 = 2.12.11-12.el7
           Removing: gtk-sharp2-2.12.11-12.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               gtk-sharp2 = 2.12.11-12.el7
           Updated By: gtk-sharp2-2.12.26-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
               gtk-sharp2 = 2.12.26-0
           Available: gtk-sharp2-2.12.11-7.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               gtk-sharp2 = 2.12.11-7.el7.nux  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Does anybody have an idea how can I fix yum to work it out?

Kind regards.

---

still problems. Launching yum distro-sync:

```
    Error: Package: mono-complete-4.6.1.5-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (@download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: mono-data = 4.6.1.5
           Removing: mono-data-4.6.1.5-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (@download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
               mono-data = 4.6.1.5-0.xamarin.1
           Downgraded By: mono-data-2.10.8-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               mono-data = 2.10.8-9.el7
Error: Package: mono-complete-4.6.1.5-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (@download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: mono-data-sqlite = 4.6.1.5
           Removing: mono-data-sqlite-4.6.1.5-0.xamarin.1.x86_64 (@download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
               mono-data-sqlite = 4.6.1.5-0.xamarin.1
           Downgraded By: mono-data-sqlite-2.10.8-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               mono-data-sqlite = 2.10.8-9.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Something is still going wrong....I got even more than these above errors

Comment: Plese use the edit functionality to add information to your post, not the answer field.

Comment: You should manually remove the conflicting packages, then.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed some third-party repositories, all of which ship incompatible versions of the same package.

The repos shipping bad packages are:

- nux-dextop
- download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_

To resolve the problem:

1. Remove the files which supply these repos from the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory.
2. Fix any pre-existing package problems that may have been caused by these repos, with `yum distro-sync`.
3. Try your installation again.